# Where is `Allocation stack` tab in Chrome 53

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm reading [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/) about memory profiling. One of it's screenshots shows `Allocation stack` tab:

[image]

In my Chrome of version 53 there is no such tab:

[image]

Where did it go? How can I find the information presented in `Allocation stack` in Chrome 53?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use this feature you need to go to `Dev Tools -> Settings` and enable `Record heap allocation stack traces`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you cannot track stack from the snapshot directly.
But you can do this by recording an allocation profile:
[image: allocation profile]

Comment: yes, it's supposed to be there, but it's not. what's you version of Chrome?

Comment: I apt-get upgrade and I'll dig this !

Comment: can you attach the screenshot?

Comment: It's the same as I posted earlier... :(

Comment: ah, I see, you referring to the different tab. check question again, I highlighted the tab I'm looking for

Comment: I've found the solution, please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39723501/2545680).